# Idiomatic use of atom in a web crawler

Tags: clojure

For example in a web crawler, it maintains a global set of visited URLs. Once a worker started working on a URL or has completed a URL, other workers should not take the same URL. One way to implement this in Java is to put visited URLs in a `ConcurrentHashMap` (a Set is better probably). Each worker looks at the map before visiting a URL

```
if (visited.putIfAbsent(url, true) == null) {
  crawl(url);
} else {
  // do nothing
}
```

In Clojure, I use a set in an `atom`. Each time I'm about to swap in a new set with the latest visited URL, the swap function should check if the set has this URL already. If the URL exists, the worker should stop from there. To be able to tell the worker if swap succeeds, I had to save the return value in the global state like `[visited-urls last-swap-succeeded]`

```
(def state (atom [#{} nil]))
(defn f [state key] (let [[visited-urls l] state] (if (visited-urls key) [visited-urls false] [(conj (visited-urls key) true]))))
```

Workers should do

```
(when (second (swap! state f url)) (crawl url))
```

It works but looks quite ugly to me. The problem is that the swap function doesn't allow a return value to the callsite. Is there better way to do this in Clojure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refs were kinda made for this sort of thing. Here's a simple way to do it

```
(when (dosync (when-not (@visited-urls-ref url-to-visit)
                (alter visited-urls-ref conj url-to-visit)))
  ; continue crawling url-to-visit
  )
```

I can't imagine it would add any significant overhead for a web crawler.

Personally, assuming the order in which urls are visited is unimportant, I'd create a core.async channel  with a `dedupe` transducer and simply have all the workers put/take urls to/from that.

Comment: This is what refs where made for :-)